# Autocomplete won't turn off on input

Tags: html, forms, input

I have an input on a page that looks like this:

```
<input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' autocomplete='off' spellcheck='false' value='' />
```

Though when the page loads the background colour of the input box changes to yellow and is autocompleted even though I have added the correct syntax:

```
autocomplete='off'
```

As you can see from the code I have tried to set the value of the input to none but to no avail

The browser I am using is the most up to date version of chrome.

I have also tried to add the autocomplete to the form but that doesn't help either

Please say if you would like to see any other code

**Edit**

I managed to find a hacky way to do it which is to add another input in the form with the same name as the input then hide the input using css and set the value to a space though there must be a cleaner way of doing it.

The code looks like this:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type="text" name='username' style="display: none;" value=" ">
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' autocomplete='off' spellcheck='false' value='' />
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' autocomplete='off' spellcheck='false' value='' />
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Isn't that a browser setting which you - as a developer - can't do anything about?

Comment: found a hacky way @Dreamonic